# Excel - How do I create a cumulative sum column within a group?

Tags: excel, group-by, sum, cumulative-sum

In Excel, I have an hours log that looks like this:

```
PersonID   Hours   JobCode
1          7       1
1          6       2
1          8       3
1          10      1
2          5       3
2          3       5
2          12      2
2          4       1
```

What I would like to do is create a column with a running total, but only within each PersonID so I want to create this:

```
PersonID   Hours   JobCode    Total
1          7       1          7 
1          6       2          13
1          8       3          21
1          10      1          31
2          5       3          5
2          3       5          8
2          12      2          20
2          4       1          24
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In D2 and fill down:

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your data starts in cell A1, this formula will accumulate the hours until it finds a change in person ID.

`=IF(A2=A1,D1+B2,B2)`

Put the formula in cell D2, and copy down for each row of your data.

Comment: You may want to also declare that it requires that the data be sorted or it will restart the sum.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, I was sorta assuming that based on the OPs example